# Creating subdirectories within a directory and be able to save data into it

Tags: android, audio, directory, saving-data

I'm new to android developing, and I'm in need of help. I've got two problems which are:

1. I don't know how to create two subdirectories inside my main directory. I know how to create subdirectory inside of a directory (`File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"Saling-Wika/Audio&Text Files");`), but what I do want is there would be two subdirectories inside of my main subdirectory (The Audio Files & Text Files are different two subdirectories inside the Saling-Wika directory which is the main directory).
2. I don't know how I'm gonna be able to save my data into the subdirectories I've created.
   Here is the code of my record module where the audio data is coming from:

   ```
   public class RecordModule extends Activity {

   Button SpeakBtn, StopBtn;
   private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
   private String outputFile = null;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.recordmodule);

       SpeakBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SpeakBtn);
       StopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopBtn);

       StopBtn.setEnabled(false);
       SpeakBtn.setEnabled(true);
       SimpleDateFormat datetime = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
       String format = datetime.format(new Date());
       outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + format + ".3gp";

       myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
       myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
       myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
       myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
       myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

       SpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               try {
                   myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                   myAudioRecorder.start();
               }

               catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               SpeakBtn.setEnabled(false);
               StopBtn.setEnabled(true);

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });

       StopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               myAudioRecorder.stop();
               myAudioRecorder.release();
               myAudioRecorder = null;

               StopBtn.setEnabled(false);
               SpeakBtn.setEnabled(true);

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });
   }
   ```

I want my audio data will be stored into the Audio Files directory, but I don't know how I'm gonna be able to do that. Please help me.

Comment: Well make your subdirectories separately. Your question is so strange. If you can make a subdirectory then you can make another i would think.

Comment: I've finally  worked on making subdirectories separately, so the first problem is solved. How about the second one? Would you help me? @greenapps

Comment: Well it looks that you ordered myAudioRecorder to do that. Is that true? Then why didnt you say so? You also forgot to tell whats happening now. Where are you indicating the right directory to your recorder?

Comment: I'm in confusion, @greenapps. Yes myAudioRecorder does it. What do you mean by where am I indicating the right directory to my recorder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved my problems, and here are the solutions I've done:

```
String folder_main = "Saling-Wika"

File MainDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorage();, folder_main);
if (!MainDir.exists()){
   MainDir.mkdirs();
}

File f1 = new File (Environment.getExternalStorage() + "/" + folder_main, "Audio Files");
if (!MainDir.exists()){
   MainDir.mkdirs();
}

File f2 = new File (Environment.getExternalStorage() + "/" + folder_main, "Text Files");
if (!MainDir.exists()){
   MainDir.mkdirs();
}
}
```

Here is the code how I've created two subdirectories (Audio & Text Files folders) inside of the main directory (Saling-Wika fodler).

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Saling-Wika/Audio Files/" + format + ".3gp";
```

And here is how my audio files are being saved into the Audio Files folder.