# Viewing your data from your device's storage

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, view, storage

Along with these - [Creating subdirectories within a directory and be able to save data into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381733/creating-subdirectories-within-a-directory-and-be-able-to-save-data-into-it?noredirect=1#comment58485177_35381733) - solved questions I've made, I have a new problem which has to be solved, of course, with the help of you guys.

And that problem is that how I'm gonna be able to view the recorded audio files from my device's storage (you can check my code on my previous thread/link above)? Like if the user click a button, the button will redirect the user into the storage and let him/her to select any of the files that has been saved into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list the files in a directory, you may use the following:

```
File directory = new File(path_of_the_directory);        
File file[] = directory.listFiles();
```

File.listFile() can also get a filter funtcion which may help you getting only the audio files from those directories.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11015925/1843141) for a complete example matching your needs.

Comment: I get the idea, but not that well. Would you please explain more how to implement that way (like giving me an example/link?

Comment: This has surely helped my problem! Thank you for your help.